# how to call Flutter Function after contact change notification from Native(Swift & Kotlin)

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, kotlin

So I am trying to update contacts upon change notification. I was unable to find any flutter plugins that did so(If you do know any plugins that does so please let me know!! ). I decided to implement the notifications and send a call to do a functionfrom native to flutter. How do you do that? I am really confused.

Comment: You could look into the source code of the workmanager plugin (https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager).

Comment: @bennik2000 good idea. Let me go do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found this really nice plugin recently. It was hidden when I was searching for it.

https://github.com/Ben-Baert/flutter_listentocontacts

Good Luck,

Ronny McNamara